# Get range days of week

Tags: php, datetime

I have for example:

$week_number = '13';
$year = '2012';

13 week in 2012 year this is range days from **26.03.2012** to **1.04.2012**. How can i get and show this with PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) function understands a nicely nuanced grammar for describing times.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("America/Toronto");

$week_number = '13';
$year = '2012';

$epoch_start = strtotime($year . "0101 + " . $week_number . " weeks - 6 days");
$epoch_end   = strtotime($year . "0101 + " . $week_number . " weeks");

print "Start: " . strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $epoch_start) . "\n";
print "  End: " . strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $epoch_end) . "\n";

?>
```

Note that `strtotime()` appears to count *full* weeks, starting on Sundays.  So January 1st 2011 would have been considered to be "week zero" of that year.

YMMV.  Salt to taste.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... if you only have the week number and the year then it is not that easy. But you can use the following:

```
<?php

$week = '13';
$year = '2012';

$firstDayOfYear = strtotime('01.01.'.$year);
$oneWeek = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;
$dateStart = $firstDayOfYear + $oneWeek * ($week - 1);
$dateEnd = $dateStart + $oneWeek;

echo 'From: ' . date('d.m.Y', $dateStart) . '<br>';
echo 'To: ' . date('d.m.Y', $dateEnd) . '<br>'; 

?>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I highly recommend standardizing on YYYY-mm-dd for dates.  Different countries have different legacy conventions, so you never know whether 02.03.2012 is February third or March second.  But 2012-03-02 is clear to everyone, and sorts better.